# Как проходит сравнение объектов в mapStateToProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Подскажите пожалуйста, как проходит сравнение объектов в mapStateToProps для определения того, нужно ли перерендерить компонент. Интересует вот такой случай. Есть в сторе стейт:

```
const state = {
    first: {
        second: {
            data: {
               a: 2, b: 3
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В mapStateToProps я получаю доступ к data и надеюсь, что когда у меня поменяется a или b то компонента перерендерится.

```
{
data: state.first.second.data
}
```

Понимаю, что будет сравниваться data, и при этом по ссылке. Но будут ли сравниваться first и second? Если нет, то зачем в reducer тогда рекомендуется делать копии на всех уровнях вложенности? Например, я хочу изменить a и мне нужно сначала сделать копию ...first, потом копию ...second и уже потом data: {...state.first.second.data, a}. Если у меня сравниваются между собой только ссылки на data, то я могу не делать копи на first и second? Или же сравнение происходит по-другому?

Answer (score 0):

В React-Redux mapStateToProps работает **к компоненту**, никакого мониторинга для определения необходимости изменения не происходит и при каждом изменении состояния компоненту передается обособленная копия.

> При получение обособленной копии сегмента состояния необходимость применения обновления к DOM древу определяет непосредственно React